# CameraSource.takephoto rotate

Tags: android, google-vision

Using Google Vision `CameraSource.takephoto` i want to take photo to detect face, but photos are rotated. I had tried to rotate it using my legacy code

```
val ei = ExifInterface(imageUri.getPath())
val orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED)

Log.d("BitmapProcessor", "orientation $orientation")

when (orientation) {
    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> rotateImage(img, 90f)
    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> rotateImage(img, 180f)
    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> rotateImage(img, 270f)
    else -> return
}
```

but `ExifInterface.getAttribureInt` always return 0 so image keep wrong rotation